# missing data in pandas web.DataReader yahoo

Tags: stock, yahoo

I am collecting data from yahoo, it works fine for more than 3 months. Then in last week I noticed that datas from 22.4.2021 is missing till today.

When I print the stockData, here is the last records :
...
...
2021-04-20   7.52  7.07  7.35   7.13   4119197.0       7.13
2021-04-21   7.36  7.13  7.16   7.25   3110870.0       7.25
2021-04-22   7.73  7.10  7.22   7.59  13178439.0       7.59
2021-05-06  10.08  9.48  9.52   9.93   2753885.0       9.93

As you see, datas are missing. It's because of yahoo or panda function, Could you help me to fix it ?.

Alper

Comment: startDate = "2021-01-01"
    endDate = str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    ticker = code.strip() + ".IS"
    try:
        stockData = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start=startDate, end=endDate)
        # stockData = data.get_data_yahoo(ticker, startDate, endDate)
        print(stockData)
        stockData.reset_index(inplace=True)  # Reset Index
    except:

Comment: Consider editing your original question to add the applicable script. That will get more attention the in a comment.